# How to create an Order Summary Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props, mern

I'd like to create an order summary component on the right hand side as shown below: [How the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc6Li.png)

However, I'm not sure how to go about this as I am quite new to MERN stack. This is the component for the how **the restaurant details are displayed**:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Grid, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { restaurantDetails } from "../../actions/restaurants";
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { LinearProgress } from "@material-ui/core";

import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import OrderSummary from "./OrderSummary/OrderSummary";

const RestaurantDetails = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let { _id } = useParams();

  const [restaurantInfo, setRestaurantInfo] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      dispatch(restaurantDetails(_id)).then((res) => setRestaurantInfo(res));
      console.log("this is restaurantInfo" + restaurantInfo);
      console.log(_id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return !restaurantInfo ? (
    <CircularProgress />
  ) : (
    <Container>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value="20" color="secondary" />;
      <Row>
        <Col sm={8}>
          {" "}
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>{restaurantInfo.name} </Paper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>{restaurantInfo.categoryname1}</Paper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>{restaurantInfo.categoryname2}</Paper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <div className="">
                  <img alt="" className="" src="images/3981417.jpg" />
                  <div className="">
                    <div className="">
                      <h3 className="">{restaurantInfo.itemName11}</h3>
                      <p className="">description here</p>
                      <h6 className="">£{restaurantInfo.itemPrice11}</h6>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        Add To Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <div className="">
                  <img alt="" className="" src="images/3981417.jpg" />
                  <div className="">
                    <div className="">
                      <h3 className="">{restaurantInfo.itemName12}</h3>
                      <p className="">description here</p>
                      <h6 className="">£{restaurantInfo.itemPrice12}</h6>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        Add To Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <div className="">
                  <img alt="" className="" src="images/3981417.jpg" />
                  <div className="">
                    <div className="">
                      <h3 className="">{restaurantInfo.itemName21}</h3>
                      <p className="">description here</p>
                      <h6 className="">£{restaurantInfo.itemPrice21}</h6>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        Add To Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <div className="">
                  <img alt="" className="" src="images/3981417.jpg" />
                  <div className="">
                    <div className="">
                      <h3 className="">{restaurantInfo.itemName22}</h3>
                      <p className="">description here</p>
                      <h6 className="">£{restaurantInfo.itemPrice22}</h6>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        Add To Order
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <OrderSummary />
      </Row>
    </Container>
    // <div>
    //   <h2>Restaurant id is: {_id}</h2>
    //   <h2>Restaurant name is: {restaurantInfo.name}</h2>
    // </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantDetails;
```

This is the **Order Summary component** at the moment. Obviously, I would like to display the item names and prices when they are added in order to checkout

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Grid, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import { Divider } from "@material-ui/core";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
const OrderTotal = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Col sm={4}>
        {" "}
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardHeader title="Order Summary" className={classes.header} />
          <Divider variant="middle" />
          <CardContent>
            <div className={classes.list}>
              <Row>
                <Col sm={6}>
                  <Typography align="center">Display Item</Typography>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={6}>
                  <Typography align="center">Display Prices</Typography>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
          <Divider variant="middle" />
          <CardActions className={classes.action}>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
              Order Now
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OrderTotal;
```

How do I implement this? How do I pass the prices and names to the order summary component and list them whenever they are added or deleted? I will really appreciate it as I can't seem to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the current cart items in the redux state.  You will need an action that adds an item to the cart.  Your reducer needs to handle this action and update the cart data.  Here is a very basic implementation:

```
const orderSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'order',
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    status: 'unsubmitted'
  },
  reducers: {
    addToOrder: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload);
    },
    submitOrder: (state) => {
      state.status = 'pending';
    }
  }
})

export const orderReducer = orderSlice.reducer;

export const {addToOrder, submitOrder} = orderSlice.actions;
```

Your "Add To Order" `Button` needs an `onClick` handler that dispatches your action.

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  onClick={() => dispatch(addToOrder({
    name: restaurantInfo.itemName12, 
    price: restaurantInfo.itemPrice12
  }))}
>
  Add To Order
</Button>
```

Your `OrderTotal` component would use a `useSelector` hook to access the cart data from redux.

```
const orderItems = useSelector(state => state.order.items);
const orderTotal = orderItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);
```

As a sidenote, you probably should not store `restaurantInfo` in your component state since it seems like it's already being set in redux.  Instead you should access it with a `useSelector`.

Comment: Hi Linda, I tried implementing this but unfortunately, it doesn't work :( when the user clicks the 'add to order' button, nothing is executed

Comment: If you can post a CodeSandbox or something I can look at it.